# Trying to understand cross_entropy loss in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

This is a very newbie question but I'm trying to wrap my head around cross_entropy loss in Torch so I created the following code:

```
x = torch.FloatTensor([
                        [1.,0.,0.]
                       ,[0.,1.,0.]
                       ,[0.,0.,1.]
                       ])

print(x.argmax(dim=1))

y = torch.LongTensor([0,1,2])
loss = torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(x, y)

print(loss)
```

which outputs the following:

```
tensor([0, 1, 2])
tensor(0.5514)
```

What I don't understand is given my input matches the expected output why is the loss not 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because the input you give to your cross entropy function is not the probabilities as you did but the logits to be transformed into probabilities with this formula:

```
probas = np.exp(logits)/np.sum(np.exp(logits), axis=1)
```

So here the matrix of probabilities pytorch will use in your case is:

```
[0.5761168847658291,  0.21194155761708547,  0.21194155761708547]
[0.21194155761708547, 0.5761168847658291, 0.21194155761708547]
[0.21194155761708547,  0.21194155761708547, 0.5761168847658291]
```

Comment: From a mathematical point of view, OP needs to transform the `y` into a probability distribution

Comment: Yes, if we change the input to like:x = torch.FloatTensor([
                        [10.,0.,0.]
                       ,[0.,10.,0.]
                       ,[0.,0.,10.]
                       ]), then the F.cross_entropy result will be close to zero, so F.cross_entropy is expecting the larger the difference between ground truth and other classes, the better, not ground truth = 1 is the best.

Answer (score 4):

`torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy` function combines `log_softmax`(softmax followed by a logarithm) and `nll_loss`(negative log likelihood loss) in a single
function, i.e. it is equivalent to `F.nll_loss(F.log_softmax(x, 1), y)`.

Code:

```
x = torch.FloatTensor([[1.,0.,0.],
                       [0.,1.,0.],
                       [0.,0.,1.]])
y = torch.LongTensor([0,1,2])

print(torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy(x, y))

print(F.softmax(x, 1).log())
print(F.log_softmax(x, 1))

print(F.nll_loss(F.log_softmax(x, 1), y))
```

output:

```
tensor(0.5514)
tensor([[-0.5514, -1.5514, -1.5514],
        [-1.5514, -0.5514, -1.5514],
        [-1.5514, -1.5514, -0.5514]])
tensor([[-0.5514, -1.5514, -1.5514],
        [-1.5514, -0.5514, -1.5514],
        [-1.5514, -1.5514, -0.5514]])
tensor(0.5514)
```

Read more about `torch.nn.functional.cross_entropy` loss function from [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#cross-entropy).

Answer (score -1):

Complete, copy/paste runnable example showing an example categorical cross-entropy loss calculation via:
-paper+pencil+calculator
-NumPy
-PyTorch

Other than minor rounding differences all 3 come out to be the same:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

import numpy as np

def main():

    ### paper + pencil + calculator calculation #################

    """
    predictions before softmax:
                  columns
               (4 categories)
        rows     1, 4, 1, 1
    (3 samples)  5, 1, 2, 1
                 1, 2, 5, 1

    ground truths (NOT one hot encoded)
          1, 0, 2

    preds softmax calculation:
    (e^1/(e^1+e^4+e^1+e^1)), (e^4/(e^1+e^4+e^1+e^1)), (e^1/(e^1+e^4+e^1+e^1)), (e^1/(e^1+e^4+e^1+e^1))
    (e^5/(e^5+e^1+e^2+e^1)), (e^1/(e^5+e^1+e^2+e^1)), (e^2/(e^5+e^1+e^2+e^1)), (e^1/(e^5+e^1+e^2+e^1))
    (e^1/(e^1+e^2+e^5+e^1)), (e^2/(e^1+e^2+e^5+e^1)), (e^5/(e^1+e^2+e^5+e^1)), (e^1/(e^1+e^2+e^5+e^1))

    preds after softmax:
    0.04332, 0.87005, 0.04332, 0.04332
    0.92046, 0.01686, 0.04583, 0.01686
    0.01686, 0.04583, 0.92046, 0.01686

    categorical cross-entropy loss calculation:
    (-ln(0.87005) + -ln(0.92046) + -ln(0.92046)) / 3 = 0.10166

    Note the loss ends up relatively low because all 3 predictions are correct
    """


    ### calculation via NumPy ###################################

    # predictions from model (just made up example data in this case)
    # rows = 3 samples, cols = 4 categories
    preds = np.array([[1, 4, 1, 1],
                      [5, 1, 2, 1],
                      [1, 2, 5, 1]], dtype=np.float32)

    # ground truths, NOT one hot encoded
    gndTrs = np.array([1, 0, 2], dtype=np.int64)

    preds = softmax(preds)

    loss = calcCrossEntropyLoss(preds, gndTrs)

    print('\n' + 'NumPy loss = ' + str(loss) + '\n')

    ### calculation via PyTorch #################################

    # predictions from model (just made up example data in this case)
    # rows = 3 samples, cols = 4 categories
    preds = torch.tensor([[1, 4, 1, 1],
                          [5, 1, 2, 1],
                          [1, 2, 5, 1]], dtype=torch.float32)

    # ground truths, NOT one hot encoded
    gndTrs = torch.tensor([1, 0, 2], dtype=torch.int64)

    loss = F.cross_entropy(preds, gndTrs)

    print('PyTorch loss = ' + str(loss) + '\n')
# end function

def softmax(x: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    numSamps = x.shape[0]

    for i in range(numSamps):
        x[i] = np.exp(x[i]) / np.sum(np.exp(x[i]))
    # end for

    return x
# end function

def calcCrossEntropyLoss(preds: np.ndarray, gndTrs: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    assert len(preds.shape) == 2
    assert len(gndTrs.shape) == 1
    assert preds.shape[0] == gndTrs.shape[0]

    numSamps = preds.shape[0]

    mySum = 0.0
    for i in range(numSamps):
        # Note: in numpy, "log" is actually natural log (ln)
        mySum += -1 * np.log(preds[i, gndTrs[i]])
    # end for

    crossEntLoss = mySum / numSamps
    return crossEntLoss
# end function

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

program output:

```
NumPy loss = 0.10165966302156448

PyTorch loss = tensor(0.1017)
```